# Communicate with RS-232 using VISA and C#

Tags: c#, serial-port, visa

Is there C# example code to communicate with a device through an RS-232 serial port using [VISA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Instrument_Software_Architecture)?

I just want to issue some simple commands and queries to the device as well as open and close it, of course.

Comment: Thank you all for the info supplied. Just after midnight I was send a solution from a support engineer at Agilent who solved my problem, which as I guessed was very simple.

Thanks again, George.

Answer (score 0):

There is sample code here:

[C# and Visual Basic .NET Instrument Control Tutorial](http://zone.ni.com/devzone/cda/tut/p/id/2739)

It uses National Instrument software:

> "The VISA .NET API is an
>   object-oriented interface made up of a
>   set of .NET classes to communicate
>   with instruments with VISA. You can
>   use .NET compliant languages such as C#
>   and Visual Basic .NET."

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that its an Agilent scope I am using and this seems to be a bit different to the NI one.

I have asked Agilent several times for help with this and as you can see I am still looking. I find it hard to believe nobody has already tried to do this relatively simple thing with their scopes alrewady, after all, what are the RS-232 communication modules for anyway ? Mumble mutter.

Comment: Perhaps you should update your question with this information.

Comment: What country are you in ? We use HPLC systems from Agilent and I am under the impression that their service is OK.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the answer I was looking for.

It appears all you need to do to access an RS-232 serial port instead of a USB port in VISA is change the USB id string to the RS-232 string (ASRL1::INSTR).

I knew it was going to be simple, just not that simple.

Thanks for all the other ideas.